# Reusable directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which takes an event when a change is detected in an input, I would like to create many inputs with the same directive.

For example:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model='val'  caret="2"><br/>
    <input ng-model'"val2' caret="2"><br/>
    <input ng-model'"val3' caret="2"><br/>
    <input ng-model'"val4' caret="2"><br/>
     ....
    <input ng-model'"valn' caret="2"><br/>
  </body>
```

The problem is that the first parameter of scope.$watch is the model name. How can I make the scope.$watch work with dynamic inputs?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

`scope.$watch('val', function(newValue, oldValue) {`

to

`scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {`

and it would work. You put a watch on attribute value for `ng-model`

see my plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/U8An4LJwzneZWv2nUNCT?p=preview

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but it doesn't print all the models that use the directive. In this example (http://plnkr.co/edit/aqJzrqAgrJZ6cjdtatlr?p=preview) , it prints Val5 , but the others doesn't print.